# Unable to install Skype in Ubuntu 13.04 on HP Envy 17

Tags: installation, 13.04, skype, hp

I have a HP Envy 17 3d Notebook on which I installed Ubuntu 13.04 today (replaced the Windows 7 at installation). After Ubuntu installation, I started downloading & installing software from Ubuntu Software Center. I couldn't find Skype in Ubuntu Software Center, so I went to [Skype.com](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) and started downloading from there.  After downloading, it showed up in Ubuntu Software Center and I clicked install. After some time the Skype icon shows up in Dash, but the application doesn't launch.

Please help me.  I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Which file did you download?

Answer (score 1):

check out the fifth item
The links below is to fix this issue with proprietary Nvidia drivers (and possibly AMD) and Skype:
[webup8 link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.